# SQL Query - Table from field

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

This is my situation. I have different tables, by example:

**TABLE A**

```
Name | Phone              
John   123   
Mick   233
```

**TABLE B**

```
Department | Position          
IT            xxx   
HR            yyy
```

And the next configuration table is created dynamically via web:

**TABLE C**

```
Source | Field  
TABLE A    Name   
TABLE B    Department
```

When I run the application, I read the Table C and I need to generate the data.
In this case, I need to list all the names from TABLE A and all the departments from TABLE B.

How can I query this? I hope somebody can help me.

Cheers!

Comment: So you want a query to create table C, so that it lists the names from table A and the depts from table B? If I understand this correctly, you will need some field to relate table A to table B (like an employee ID, or something). If you already have table C, then your problem is solved already, as it has both the names and the departments, right? You say you read from table C, this makes it seem like it is already created?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What DBMS do you use. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL .... ?

Comment: @Fabricio: In the example, do you want to produce a list of all Names from Table A, followed by a list of all Departments from Table B? Or do you wish to relate them somehow - if so, how?

Comment: Logan, the TABLE C is created via web. Once is created, I need to query that table and get the information. For example, if in the TABLE C I got "TABLE A | Departments", I need to list all the departments from the table A. The question is, how can I query the TABLE C to access to the TABLE A and get the info? Because is a field. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do this in sql - which I would not recommend if you can not trust the content of TABLE C - then you will need to construct a variable that contains the sql query, then execute that sql query dynamically. How to do this will entirely depend on your DBMS. An example in MySQL (which assumes that TABLE C has only one row):

```
SELECT @sql:=CONCAT("SELECT ",field," FROM ",source) FROM TABLE_C;
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s1;
```

SQL Server syntax:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = "SELECT " + field + " FROM " + source FROM TABLE_C
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO
```

Since TABLE C will certainly have more than one row you will have to iterate through TABLE C. This can be done with a CURSOR, and again the exact details will be dependent on your DBMS.

Importantly, be aware that this is very dangerous if as you state TABLE C is created from the web. You have no guarantee what is in the FIELD and SOURCE fields: they could be filled with a sql injection attack by anyone with a little SQL knowledge. What you may need to do is safely validate that TABLE C's contents are actual tables/columns via safely parameterized database meta-queries.

Comment: the TABLE C is created via web. Once is created, I need to query that table and get the information. For example, if in the TABLE C I got "TABLE A | Departments", I need to list all the departments from the table A. The question is, how can I query the TABLE C to access to the TABLE A and get the info? Because is a field. You know what I mean?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, and that is what my answer addresses. The only way to do this kind of query is via dynamic-sql: query table C to create a character string that contains query that you actually want to run, then run that query via an EXECUTE call. Most if not all database servers allow dynamic sql for just these kinds of requirements. BUT, this is dangerous since table C could contain a SQL injection attack, so you really should check that the contents of table C are actual tables/columns before you construct the dynamic query.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server and I can't do it. Dynamic SQL is something new for me and I'm confused. Do I need to declare "FIELD" and "SOURCE"? How can I do it?

Comment: I've added a SQL Server sample to the answer. In SQL Server you would use the sp_execute stored procedure to execute the command. The command would be contained in a variable of type NVARCHAR.

Comment: @Fabricio: `Source` and `Field` are the names of the columns you gave TABLE C in your question - if your actual column names are different, I suggest you use those instead.

Comment: Ok, it works! Now, with this I only get one record. I'm trying to create a CURSOR, but it doesn't work.. any ideas?

Comment: Cursors are tricky at first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx is where to start, especially the working examples at the end of the page.

Answer (score -1):

```
 select ta.Name, tb.Department 
 from TABLEA ta, TABLEB  tb
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also: I would recommend to **always** use the proper ANSI JOIN Syntax - something like `SELECT ta.Name, tb.Department FROM dbo.TableA INNER JOIN dbo.TableB tb ON .......` (or use another JOIN, if appropriate) - don't just list tables separated by commas - that's dangerous, it's not clear if you really want a Cartesian product (like here) or if you just happened to forget a JOIN condition in the WHERE.... just messy